# Display labels on Chart.js in Ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic2, label, chart.js

I'm struggling to have labels always displayed on a chart created with Chart.js in a Ionic 2 app.
I'd like to have something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/doughnut-chart-6iuguq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
but I'm not able to load correctly this js plugin https://github.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js

Any help to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the import statement to the top of the controller (.ts file)

```
import 'chart.piecelabel.js';
```